# save image Using file picker in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-phone-8.1, filepicker

I am adding Students and save Profile details to the SQLite database. Added Student Profiles are Shown in a Listview as below.

[image]    [image]

I want to add a picture of the student using a file picker and save it. How can I achieve that?. Any suggestion or similar example would be more helpful.

So far My codes

```
   private string mruToken = null;   
    private NavigationHelper navigationHelper;
    public AddConatct()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.navigationHelper = new NavigationHelper(this);
        this.Loaded += LoadSchoolToCombo;
        this.navigationHelper.LoadState += navigationHelper_LoadState;
        this.navigationHelper.SaveState += navigationHelper_SaveState;

    }
    private async void navigationHelper_LoadState(object sender, LoadStateEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.PageState != null && e.PageState.ContainsKey("mruToken"))
        {
            object value = null;
            if (e.PageState.TryGetValue("mruToken", out value))
            {
                if (value != null)
                {
                    mruToken = value.ToString();

                    // Open the file via the token that you stored when adding this file into the MRU list.
                    Windows.Storage.StorageFile file =
                        await Windows.Storage.AccessCache.StorageApplicationPermissions.MostRecentlyUsedList.GetFileAsync(mruToken);

                    if (file != null)
                    {
                        // Open a stream for the selected file.
                        Windows.Storage.Streams.IRandomAccessStream fileStream =
                            await file.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read);

                        // Set the image source to a bitmap.
                        Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage bitmapImage =
                            new Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage();

                        bitmapImage.SetSource(fileStream);
                        img.Source = bitmapImage;

                        // Set the data context for the page.
                        this.DataContext = file;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    private void navigationHelper_SaveState(object sender, SaveStateEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(mruToken))
        {
            e.PageState["mruToken"] = mruToken;
        }

    }


   private async void PickPhoto_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e){
        Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileOpenPicker openPicker = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileOpenPicker();
        openPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;
        openPicker.ViewMode = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;

        // Filter to include a sample subset of file types.
        openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Clear();
        openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".bmp");
        openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".png");
        openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpeg");
        openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");

        // Open the file picker.
        Windows.Storage.StorageFile file = await openPicker.PickSingleFileAsync();

        // file is null if user cancels the file picker.
        if (file != null)
        {
            // Open a stream for the selected file.
            Windows.Storage.Streams.IRandomAccessStream fileStream =
                await file.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read);

            // Set the image source to the selected bitmap.
            Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage bitmapImage =
                new Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage();

            bitmapImage.SetSource(fileStream);
            img.Source = bitmapImage;
            this.DataContext = file;

            // Add picked file to MostRecentlyUsedList.
            mruToken = Windows.Storage.AccessCache.StorageApplicationPermissions.MostRecentlyUsedList.Add(file);
        }
    }

    private async void AddContact_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DatabaseHelperClass Db_Helper = new DatabaseHelperClass();//Creating object for DatabaseHelperClass.cs from ViewModel/DatabaseHelperClass.cs 
        if (NametxtBx.Text != "" & AgetxtBx.Text != "" & AddresstxtBx.Text != "" & SchoolComboBx.SelectedValue.ToString() != "" & GardienttxtBx.Text != "" & PhonetxtBx.Text != "" & LattxtBx.Text != "" & LongtxtBx.Text != "")
        {
            Db_Helper.Insert(new Contacts(NametxtBx.Text, AgetxtBx.Text, AddresstxtBx.Text, SchoolComboBx.SelectedValue.ToString(), GardienttxtBx.Text, PhonetxtBx.Text, LattxtBx.Text, LongtxtBx.Text));
            Frame.Navigate(typeof(ReadContactList));//after add contact redirect to contact listbox page 
        }
        else
        {
            MessageDialog messageDialog = new MessageDialog("Please fill all fields");//Text should not be empty 
            await messageDialog.ShowAsync();
        }
    }
```

Contacts.cs

```
public class Contacts
{
    //The Id property is marked as the Primary Key
    [SQLite.PrimaryKey, SQLite.AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Age { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string School { get; set; }
    public string Gardient { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string Latitude { get; set; }
    public string Longitude { get; set; }
    public string CreationDate { get; set; }
    public Contacts()
    {
        //empty constructor
    }
    public Contacts( string name, string age, string address, string school, string gardient, string phone_no, string latitude, string longitude)
    {

        Name = name;
        Age = age;
        Address = address;
        School = school;
        Gardient = gardient;
        PhoneNumber = phone_no;
        Latitude = latitude;
        Longitude = longitude;
        CreationDate = DateTime.Now.ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a good idea. You should save files in local folder and save path to database. In this approach

You need to save images in local folder by username or any other unique attribute as you like. I did it this way. First pick the file

```
private void choose_galary_pic_tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            FileOpenPicker openPicker = new FileOpenPicker();
            openPicker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
            openPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;
            openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");
            openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpeg");
            openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".png");
            openPicker.PickSingleFileAndContinue();
        }
        catch { }
    }
```

and now for saving the file

```
public async void ContinueFileOpenPicker(FileOpenPickerContinuationEventArgs args)
    {
        try
        {
            if (args.Files.Count > 0)
            {
                StorageFile sf = args.Files[0];
                await sf.CopyAsync(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder, args.Files[0].Name, NameCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(sf.Name);
                ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["GImage"] = sf.Name;
                var stream = await args.Files[0].OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read);
                await bitmapImage.SetSourceAsync(stream);
                userImage.Source = bitmapImage;      
            }
            else
            {

            }
        }
        catch { }
    }
```

or if you want to directly save images then Base-64 is best encoding technique to store images in SQLite. Try the below given code. One method will give you base-64 encoded string of StorageFile & other one will return you BitmapImage object, which can be set as source of `<Image />`.

```
private async Task<BitmapImage> Base64StringToBitmap(string source)
{
    var ims = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
    var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(source);
    var dataWriter = new DataWriter(ims);
    dataWriter.WriteBytes(bytes);
    await dataWriter.StoreAsync();
    ims.Seek(0);
    var img = new BitmapImage();
    img.SetSource(ims);
    return img;
}

private async Task<string> ConvertStorageFileToBase64String(StorageFile imageFile)
{
var stream = await imageFile.OpenReadAsync();

using (var dataReader = new DataReader(stream))
{
    var bytes = new byte[stream.Size];
    await dataReader.LoadAsync((uint)stream.Size);
    dataReader.ReadBytes(bytes);

    return Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
}
```

}

Hope it helps.

Comment: How in ContinueFileOpenPicker save the image. If it is the best way to save the path how to do so? help me

Comment: Here continueFileOpenPicker method is saving the image in local folder using CopyAsync method. If you want it to save in database then get the file Path property and save that in database.

Comment: I manged to save image as base64 String and retrive it back as image with the help of your code. Now I am facing trouble to display the image in a List view as I opened another Question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34637185/binding-base64-string-image-into-list-view-stored-in-sqlite-database-in-windows). I really appreciate if you can help on this too.